# Best method for processing and storing analytics data

Tags: mysql, logging, analytics

I'm trying to devise a way to generate timeline based graphs for email campaigns.  Since each campaign can contain hundreds of thousands of messages, and there eventually will be hundreds or thousands of campaigns, I can't provide real time graphs, I need to somehow pre-process the logs so the graphs can be generated within a reasonable timeframe (a few seconds).

Here is a simplified version of my current idea, which works well but has a show stopping flaw:

```
CREATE TABLE message_log (
    log_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    log_campaign_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    log_message_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    log_action VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    log_timestamp INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    log_counted TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    INDEX(log_counted)
);

CREATE TABLE message_stats (
    stats_campaign_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    stats_year INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    stats_month TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    stats_day TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    stats_hour TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    stats_sent_count INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    stats_open_count INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    stats_bounce_count INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (stats_campaign_id, stats_year, stats_month, stats_day, stats_hour)
);
```

So the idea is the various log_action (sent, open, bounce) are logged in real time in the message_log table.   The message_stats table holds the processed data, which is simply a tally of sent, open, and bounced messages in 1 hour intervals. The message_log.log_counted flag indicates whether the row has been processed into message_stats.

When I need up to date stats, I simply select rows from message_log with log_counted=0, tally them up in message_stats, and set log_counted=1.  I can now quickly and easily select campaign specific or general yearly, monthly, daily, or hourly stats by grouping the various columns.

It may be more straightforward to skip the message_log altogether and simply update the message_stats table in real time, but I chose to keep the raw log data so the data can be easily regenerated at a later date, simply by truncating message_stats and setting message_log.log_counted=0 .

So far in testing this is working well, but the flaw is the graphs must be locale specific, and since the timelines are already processed based on the system timezone, there is no way to generate timezone specific graphs with this system.

Any ideas on a better approach?  I know I'm not the first person faced with this dilemma.

Answer (score 1):

Create message_stats_locale_agnostic and then modify message_stats to contain a locale column.

You now have a three step process: message_log => message_stats => message_stats_locale_agnostic.

The message_stats still contains aggregated data but it is now slicing it by locale as well, so you will end up with more rows in this table than before.

You now also need one more aggregation process which populates the message_stats_locale_agnostic table by ignoring the locale column that now exists in message_stats.  This table is essentially what you have now in message_stats.

If you need data based on locale, select from message_stats (knowing it will be a bit slower than when you select from message_stats_locale_agnostic.)  If you need data not based on locale, select from message_stats_locale_agnostic.

Comment: Thanks Macy, that makes sense but supporting at least 24 timezones offsets would mean an increase in the amount of data stored and the preprocessing time by at least 24.  I don't think that's an option.

Comment: @Rob Are you sure Rob?  A factor of 24 really isn't that much in the land of RDMS.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to not solve this problem yourself.  There are a number of analytics services or tools out there to help with the heavy lifting here (full disclosure: I started one of them).  I've made this answer a community wiki so others can add their own favorites.  But here's a list of potential solutions with my opinions about them:

1. Keen IO (my company).  Custom analytics via API.  Useful when you're thinking about building a custom analytics solution but don't want to actually build everything from scratch.  Can be used to build analytics features directly into your website or app.  Lots of developer leverage here!  But no built-in dashboards.  You have to build your own.
2. MixPanel.  Customizable analytics dashboard.  Good if you want a place to log into and view data.  Great for clicking around in a UI.  Also good for tracking and taking part in user interactions.  May become prohibitively expensive at high volumes.
3. Vertica.  Analytics DB that you deploy onto your own hardware.  Highly scalable, highly schema'd.  Many old school analytics solutions (Zynga, etc.) are built on this.
4. Hadoop-as-a-Service.  There are a number of companies offering this.  They manage the complexity of building and maintaining a Hadoop cluster.  You still have to do things like write map-reduce jobs.  Potentially a big time saver if Hadoop is what you need.

Please add more!